# If I purchased Minecraft for PS3, can I play on PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I have purchased Minecraft for PS3, however for various reasons I am dissatisfied with the PS3 experience and I would like to continue playing on PC.

Does the PS3 purchase/license allow me full access to the PC version and/or any other versions of Minecraft?

Comment: Do you mean transfering your ps3 world to your PC?

Comment: @LFM Not at all. I mean does the PS3 purchase/licence allow me full access to the PC version.

Comment: No, it does not. It's like if you wanted to get it for Xbox, you would still need to purchase a separate copy for the different platform/console.

Comment: @Ben Is there any official literature that backs this statement? I have searched and not found anything official.

Comment: @robbmj the simple fact is that even if you tried, there would be no way for you to prove that you have an existing copy on a separate platform. If there is no method like "Please enter a pre-existing game code here:" then that (I believe) should be official enough.

Comment: Incidentally, a question specifically asking for documentation is off-topic; we don't really do off-site resource requests very well.  They don't fit into the Q&A format in a good manner.  Most of them tend to be closed, too.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is pretty obious. Buying minecraft for xbox, means you have the an xbox game, that doesnt give you the right to have minecraft for pc. 2 different products. Imagine having 2 cars, you still have to buy 2 times a set of winter tires.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Purchasing the PS3 copy gives you the right to use the PS3 version. It does not give you any right to the PC version, nor will it allow your PS3 account to use the PC version.

If you want to play on PC, you'll need to buy the PC version separately.

Comment: Is there any official literature that backs this statement? I have searched and not found anything official.

Comment: @robbmj The reason for this is because there is no correlation between the three at all. The PC Version requires you to purchase an account from Mojang (on [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net)), while the console versions don't even require you to have an online account. All that is required is for you to purchase a copy of the game. All 3 versions are completely separate, therefore there is no reason to clarify that.

Comment: They are completely separate versions of the game.  The PC version is written in Java, mostly by Notch, while the XBox/PS4 versions are a complete rewrite written in C# _(and some C++, supposedly)_ by the 4J team.